# Can I use ulimit to prevent a system from overheating and rebooting?

Tags: ulimit

I was just informed about the joys of `ulimit`.

And it got me thinking...if I have a system with an old processor that keeps overheating, and let's say for sake of example; no other hardware that I could plug it into because it's too old; by limiting the amount of system resources used by a user, could that possibly keep the CPU cool and allow me to copy my stuff off of it?

I mean it sounds like a hack rather than the intended purpose of `ulimit`, but I was just wondering if that works.  I guess too though you'd have to apply it to all users on the system.  And I also suppose run level 1 would also cause a similar way of doing that.

Comment: Is the system overheating because some process is allocating too much memory or opening too many files (or anything else that `ulimit` can limit) (this would likely not be the case)? If it's overheating due to using the CPU or GPU, then `ulimit` can likely not help you.

Comment: It's probably a hardware issue caused by dirt in CPU fan/heatsink and old dry thermal grease. Cleaning fan, heatsink and CPU and applying new thermal grease will probably solve it, but maybe you need a new fan.

Comment: @Freddy Yeah that’s the plan; but in implementation it’s a bit more difficult.  I need to heat the processor up, but I’ve also got to have my dental floss in place and everything else plugged in first.  MacPro Early 2008 makes everything difficult.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not usefully, no. `ulimit` mostly limits the amount of memory of various types that a process can use (memory for direct use as well as entries in system tables such as tables of file descriptors and processes). `ulimit` can be used to kill processes that consume more than a certain amount of CPU time in total, but that's not really related to CPU temperature. A process that hogs the CPU for a few minutes might cause your system to overheat whereas using a few minutes spread over a day wouldn't be a problem.

`ulimit` can also set a limit on a process's scheduling priority, but that's not useful either, because the only way in which this prevents a process from using CPU time is if other processes use the CPU instead. For the same reason, `nice` won't keep your CPU cooler.

What will cause your CPU to run cooler is limiting its maximum frequency. Under Linux, you can do that with something like

```
echo 2097152 | tee /sys/devices/system/cpu/cpufreq/policy*/scaling_max_freq
```

This caps the CPU frequency at 2GHz ([`scaling_max_freq`](https://www.kernel.org/doc/Documentation/cpu-freq/user-guide.txt) is in kHz). Each `policy*` directory corresponds to one core.

Processors *should* be protected from overheating and slow down rather than crash (let alone catch fire, which CPUs are very well protected against in practice), but in practice sometimes they do crash.